# Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense squigglies not working for 1 solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

It's remarkable how much one comes to rely on the red squigglies once they're gone.

I have 1 c++ solution in Visual Studio 2013 where the red squigglies will not show up.  The rest of Intellisense works, except for the error checking.  I have tried:

1. Resetting all settings in Visual Studio
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio
3. Deleting the dev folder and getting latest from TFS
4. Deleting all *.sdf files in the dev folder.

This problem only appears in 1 solution, though.  I can create a new VC++ solution, and those magical red squigglies show up where they should.

Also, I'm not sure if this is related or not, but I globally lost variable highlighting in the enhanced scroll bar.  In Visual Studio 2013, if you focus the cursor over a variable, you will see little highlights appear in the scroll bar, indicating where the variable is used.  That feature no longer works across the board.  Edits (yellow), Breakpoints (red), and saves(green) work, but not variable highlighting.

Comment: C++ native or C++cli?

Comment: Does step #3 mean that the `.pdb` files were deleted (they aren't stored in TFS)?

Comment: @Steve Everything was deleted, including the .pdb files.  They are not stored in TFS.